# How to monitor a window's position with Win32?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I need to draw an overlay using WPF on top of a number of Win32 windows. In order to draw the overlay in the correct place, I will need to hook into the window move, but have no idea how to do this.  Which Win32 calls should I be looking at?

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx().  But you can't write the DLL you have to inject to detect the WM_MOVING message in a managed language.  C or C++ required.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx

Comment: How did you draw the overlay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SetWinEventHook

```
var hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART,    
    EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND, NULL, WinEventProc, 
    0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
```